# pyspark 3.x in pypi limited to hadoop 2.7.4

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, pypi

I want to `pip install pyspark` into my python3 virtual environment but the only choice I have is the PyPI version compiled with **Hadoop 2.7.4** dependencies. I need a **Hadoop 3.x** version since **2.7.4** is too old for modern AWS S3 integration.

Does anyone know why there isn't an option to `pip install pyspark` with **Hadoop 3.x** support?

Is my only option to build my own `pyspark` from source?